# Shell Script Delimiter(Enclosed by "")

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting i want to load data from text with delimiter "," i came to know that using IFS we can retrieve data with "," delimited but my requirement is to load the data with "," delimited but which is not enclosed in ""

For Eg my data is as follows :

```
shiva,kumar,gg,"4,400",uuuu
```

Output:

```
shiva
kumar
gg
4400
uuuu
```

But Output is coming as follows:

```
shiva
kumar
gg
4
400
uuuu
```

Can some one expert in shell let me know how to rectify this ?

Comment: Better to use a csv parser.

Comment: When you have duplicate delimiter, it's better you change main delimiter.

Comment: `IFS` is for field splitting, but field splitting is a far simpler procedure than parsing a comma-separated line which allows for quoted delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

As @anubhava comments, better to use a CSV parser. For example:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.parse_line($_).map {|f| f.delete ","}.join(" ")' file
```

Comment: It's ruby language not shell scripting!

Comment: I think I can be described as "expert in shell" -- this is not a task that shell is well suited for.